# Как центрировать текст в этом блоке?

Tags: css, центрирование

```css
.main {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30vh;
  left: 40vw;
}

.listBlock {
  background-color: #777777;
  color: #FFFFFF;                 
  padding: 0.4em;
}

.listBlock li{
  display: inline;       
  margin: 0.9em;
}

.listBlock a{
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.listBlock a:hover{
  color: #282828FF;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="listBlock">
    <ol class="list">
      <li><a href="Index.html">HTML</a></li>
      <li><a href="Index.html">CSS</a></li>
      <li><a href="Index.html">JavaScript</a></li>
      <li><a href="Index.html">PHP</a></li>
    </ol>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: margin: 0,padding:0 для начала списку задайте.А дальше,вариантов много,можете хоть table-row воспользоваться

Answer (score 0):

На будущее: Не советую позиционировать элементы через `position: absolute`, только при необходимости. Можно это сделать через `flexbox`, или через `display: inline-block`, что бы элемент сохранил свою ширину, и потом через `margin: 0 auto`.

```css
.main {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.listBlock {
  background-color: #777777;
  color: #FFFFFF;                 
  padding: 0.4em;
}

.listBlock li{
  display: inline;       
  margin: 0.9em;
}

.listBlock a{
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.listBlock a:hover{
  color: #282828FF;
}

.list {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="listBlock">
    <ol class="list">
      <li><a href="Index.html">HTML</a></li>
      <li><a href="Index.html">CSS</a></li>
      <li><a href="Index.html">JavaScript</a></li>
      <li><a href="Index.html">PHP</a></li>
    </ol>
  </div>
</div>
```